# French phonetic transcription to French text

Tags: expressions, traduction, terminologie, phonétique, démonstratifs

I need help in finding app or where I could convert French phonetic transcription to actual French text. I have been an assignment on it and don't even understand what the transcript means. Help

Comment: This should be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you can't theorically automate a conversion from phonetic to actual text because the correspondance between those two writings is **not bijective**:

For example if your phonetic word is **[o]**, you may have to transcript it to 9 different forms:

***eau, eaux, ô, au, aux, haut, hauts, oh, ho.***

So you must use the intelligence of the text to transcript correctly from phonetic to actual text, and no application can actually do that without an error.

Comment: You underestimate what a computer can do. Speech recognition algorithms aren't yet perfect but are getting better and better along the years. Providing IPA instead of raw sound probably simplifies the work despite prosody being lost.

Comment: I don't underestimate, dear Jiliagre: I didn't say "can't do" but I said "can't do without an error". As an IT engineer, I often had to read English pages. When I tried to have them translated into French, it was a real catastrophy, even in 2019. So, I think that your optimism is rather to overestimate what a computer can do: The translation between languages will be like a stalemate for computers during still many years to come.

Comment: Translation between languages adds a level of complexity that is not present in the OP request. My experience with Deepl is different, I'm often amazed by the quality of its work when translating foreign langages to French. Anyway, I agree perfection is unachievable but even native people can't recognize speech with a 100% reliability ;-)